# Show/hide an animated button loader while function is processing data

Tags: javascript, html, flask

I have created this submit button that will run a Python function to process data, the overall process takes between 15 - 20 seconds before results are shown, so I added an animated loading GIF:

```
<div class="col-2">
  <button class="btn btn-primary float-start" type="submit">Get Data!</button>
  <!-- Image loader -->
  <div id='loader' style='display: none;'>
   <img src='/static/img/loader.gif'> <b>Loading..</b>
  </div>
</div>
```

With the associated jQuery/JS to make it show at click and hide once the data processing done:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#form1').on('submit', function(event) {
    $.ajax({
        data : {
        input : $('#input').val(),
    },
        type : 'POST',
        url : '/price',
        beforeSend: function(){
        // Show image container
        $("#loader").show();
   },
    })
    .done(function(data) {
    if (data.error) {
        $('#ticker_id').text(data.error).show();
        $('#successAlert').hide();
        }
    else {
        $('#upper_price').text(data.upper_price).show();
        $('#errorAlert').hide();
        complete:function(data){
        // Hide image container
        $("#loader").hide();
        },
        $('')
        }
    });
        event.preventDefault();
    });
    });
</script>
```

My current issue is that the loader image doesn't show (once I fix this first step, I'll know if it hides or not)

Comment: Should be seeing a syntax error in browser dev tools console. That `complete` is invalid . My guess is you flipped around between using done and complete and broke the structure of the options object doing it

Comment: @charlietfl I tried without `complete:function` and still nothing happens

Comment: fixed it, you were right!

Comment: If you are not familiar with how to access browser dev tools console to check for errors find a tutorial on it. That should always be the first place to look when something isn't working. The majority of the error messages you encounter can be pasted right into a web search and help guide you to understanding them i

Comment: @charlietfl , yes you're right, I've relying on werkzeug a little bit too much...